# Codeigniter redirects for a new domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a website which has 2 parts - lets say A and B.

Now I want to move part A to a new domain.

Currently, the URLs are of the form:

www.xyz.com/A/controller/function - for part A

www.xyz.com/A/B/controller/function - for part B

my new links will be:

www.abc.com/controller/function - for part A

www.xyz.com/B/controller/function - for part B

Can you suggest me a good way to handle these redirects? I am using Codeigniter Framework.

Comment: Hi Amit, ccan you please tell what "which has 2 parts" mean ? 2 controllers ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same CI install for both parts? If so then this [link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/175084/) may help you.

If each part has its own CI install, don't forget you can use the same system folder for both by setting the ***$system*** variable in the ***index.php*** file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your `www.xyz.com` site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#redirect www.xyz.com/A/B/controller/function
#www.xyz.com/B/controller/function
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^A/(B/[\w]+/[\w]+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]


#redirect www.xyz.com/A/controller/function to
#www.abc.com/controller/function
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^A/([\w]+/[\w]+)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```