# redirect domain to www on codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

What would be the best way to redirect codeigniter website to www domain? The only way that comes to my mind is to use htaccess for this but can't figure out exactly how. This is the rewrite rule I'm using right now to remove index.php from the url. How should I add the redirection to www domain correctly?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.png|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See this URL**

[.htaccess Redirect non-WWW to WWW preserving URI string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685962/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-preserving-uri-string)

**Or try it**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Another example**

See this URL

[Codeigniter redirects for a new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172019/codeigniter-redirects-for-a-new-domain)

**Try it**

Try adding the following to the **.htaccess** file in the root directory of your **www.xyz.com** site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#redirect www.xyz.com/A/B/controller/function
#www.xyz.com/B/controller/function
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^A/(B/[\w]+/[\w]+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]


#redirect www.xyz.com/A/controller/function to
#www.abc.com/controller/function
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^A/([\w]+/[\w]+)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I've used the first three lines of code, but still my pages redirects like 

(mysite.com/about-us) to (www.mysite.com/index.php?/about-us)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [CNAME record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) in your DNS.

This saves an HTTP request so is the most efficient option.

Answer (score 2):

Add another condition under that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```